# Creating Data Extension via Ampscript giving error

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, error, wsdl, landing-page

I'm trying to create a data extension from a landing page using some Ampscript. So far I have got this:

```
%%[
var @jobno, @de, @deFields, @StatCode, @ts_attr, @StatMessage, @ErrorCode
set @jobno = RequestParameter("jobno")
set @de = CreateObject(@jobno)

/*CREATE DATA EXTENSION */
SetObjectProperty(@de,"Name",@jobno)
SetObjectProperty(@de,"CustomerKey",@jobno)
SetObjectProperty(@de,"Description",Concat("DE created at ",Now()))
SetObjectProperty(@de,"IsSendable","True")
SetObjectProperty(@de,"IsTestable","False")
SetObjectProperty(@de,"CategoryID","15209")

/*CREATE SENDABLE FIELD*/
Set @deFields = CreateObject("DataExtensionField")
SetObjectProperty(@deFields,"FieldType","EmailAddress")
SetObjectProperty(@deFields,"IsRequired","true")
SetObjectProperty(@deFields,"IsPrimaryKey","false")
SetObjectProperty(@deFields,"IsNillable","false")
SetObjectProperty(@deFields,"MaxLength","254")
SetObjectProperty(@deFields,"Name","Email_Address")
AddObjectArrayItem(@de,"Fields",@deFields)

SetObjectProperty(@de,"SendableDataExtensionField",@deFields)

SET @ts_attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_attr, "Name", "Email Address")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_attr, "Value", "Email Address")
SetObjectProperty(@de,"SendableSubscriberField",@ts_attr)

Set @StatCode = InvokeCreate(@de, @StatMessage, @ErrorCode)


]%%

Status = %%= v(@StatMessage) =%% -- %%= v(@ErrorCode) =%%
```

But when I run it, I get this error:

> Error Message:    Could not load type
>   'ExactTarget.Integration.WSDL.ACI_12507_APP_CAM_02' from assembly
>   'ExactTarget.Api.Generated'.   Description:   An unexpected error
>   occurred during the execution of the page.   line 0, column 0
>   Exception Info: An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a
>   CreateObject function call.  See inner exception for details.
>
> System.TypeLoadException:  Could not load type
>   'ExactTarget.Integration.WSDL.ACI_12507_APP_CAM_02' from assembly
>   'ExactTarget.Api.Generated'. Source:  mscorlib

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is "IsNillable"?  Maybe the typo is getting you?

Comment: Sadly not - 'Nillable' is indeed correct, and not 'Nullable' as you'd expect.

Comment: That's embarrassing.  OK, so a couple of thoughts: I would move the InvokeCreate call above the attribute, comment out the CreateObject("Attribute") section, and see if it works.   Secondly, I assume you are working off the documentation at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/createDataExtension.htm ?  You should be using the example using the subscriber key, not Email Address.